# tikzplotlib settings do not match

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzplotlib

I am trying to translate a matplotlib plot to tikz. This is fairly straightforward:

```
plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.xticks([], [])
plt.yticks([], [])
plt.scatter([d[0] for d in towns], [d[1] for d in towns], color="#489427", s=0.3)
# plt.savefig("pcb3038.svg")

import tikzplotlib

# tikzplotlib.save("test.tex")
tikzplotlib.get_tikz_code()
```

The result in latex shows

[image]

whereas matplotlib shows

[image]

I prefer the bottom one but somehow tikz doesn't interpret it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tikzplotlib` conversion adds the `scatter` key to the plot. This seems to make sense because the matplotlib plot is also scatter, however the `scatter` key in pgfplots is used only to change marker appearance and not to actually create a scatter plot as opposed to a line plot for example. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), page 108:

> The key `scatter` is simply a boolean variable which enables marker
> modifications. It applies only to markers and it can be combined with
> any other plot type.

In this case you do *not* want the marker modifications (i.e., the colors). Therefore you can edit the generated `pgfplots` code to remove the `scatter` key. For the size of the dots you can use the `mark size` key.

Python MWE, modified to show some dummy data:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
towns = list()
for i in range(0,3000,100):
   for j in range(0,4000,100):
      towns.append([i,j])
plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.xticks([], [])
plt.yticks([], [])
plt.scatter([d[0] for d in towns], [d[1] for d in towns], color="#489427", s=0.3)

import tikzplotlib

tikzplotlib.save("mplscatter.tex")
```

Modified `.tex` output:

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.8.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.282352941176471,0.580392156862745,0.152941176470588}

\begin{axis}[
tick pos=left,
xmin=-145, xmax=3045,
ymin=-195, ymax=4095
]
%%% MODIFIED THE LINE BELOW
\addplot [draw=color0, fill=color0, mark=*, only marks, mark size=1pt]%, scatter]
table{%
x  y
0 0
0 100
0 200
% ...
```

Result:

[image]

Note that of course it would be nice to influence the output of `tikzplotlib` from within the Python code, but I'm not sure how to do that. However, if the data does not change and the number of plots is limited then modifying the generated code seems a feasible approach.